# Using python for obtaining features from audio in unity

Tags: python, android, unity-game-engine, audio

I have to develop a android application which will capable of doing predictions on device meaning I have to perform every action on the device itself

The application has to extract features from audio and feed them to tensorflow lite model for prediction

For training the model, I extracted the features from audio using Librosa, but I am not able to find a suitable framework which can help me extract features from audio like librosa and make prediction using tflite model

I found out that I can do something using Ironpython or python.net in unity but I am still confused about how to achieve it.

So my question is whether there is way to run the python script written on android device with unity.

Also if there are other frameworks, that can help me achieve my goal of on-device prediction, ,I will welcome those suggestions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ironpython will run some python. However is everything compatible possibly not. How to do that there looks to be a fair amount of documentation for ironpython. Try it?

Answer (score 1):

It was not feasible to accomplish the task using unity effectively.

I solved the problem using chaquopy plugin for android studio, this enables you to use python with java or you can code the whole android application in python using chaquopy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).